# Trying to convert Numerical Values of Lat/Long into Spatial Data

Tags: r, spatial

I am working with a dataset that features chemical analyses from different locations within a cave, with each analysis ordered by a site number and that sites latitude and longitude. This first image is what I had done originally simply using ggplot.
[Concentrations mapped by color over map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgMvk.png)

But what I want to do is use the shapefile of the cave system from which the data is sourced from and do something similar by plotting the points over the system and then coloring them by concentration. This below is the shapefile that I uploaded
[Cave system shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8etwv.png)

So basically I want to be able to map the chemical data from my dataset used to map the first figure, but on the map of the shapefile. Initially it kept on saying that it could not plot on top of it. So I figured I had to convert the latitude and longitude into spatial coordinates that could then be mapped on the shapefile.

```
   Master_Cave_data <- Master_cave_data %>%
   st_as_sf(MastMaster_cave_data, agr = "identity", coord = Lat_DD)
```

This was what I had thought to use in order to convert the numerical Latitude cooridnates into spatial data.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please give more details about your question, show us some data and your effords for solving your problem. A good start is to show us your expected output.

Comment: So the dataset is formatted with different columns as such: site id:1 Lat:38.23440 Long-90.1389 and associated with it is different chemical analyses. I also uploaded the shapefile of the system that this data was collected from. I wanted to map out using ggplot these data points onto the shapefile

Comment: Have you heard of the [sf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) package?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to use the spatialpoints function but the syntax that other people have mentioned has kindof tripped me up.